# Как задеплоить проект?

Tags: spring, eclipse, rest

Помогите, пожалуйста, запустить проект: https://github.com/serega-sergei/test

Где тут main-class или как это делается… Возможно нужно отметить проект как Tomcat project, по принципу обычных сервлетов? Но что тогда определить в context name…

Судя по помке, context name = service, но это все равно не помогает. Не могу добавить ресурс на томкат сервер в IDE (пишет нет доступных). Попробовал собрать war и подложить в webapp сервера - тоже не помогло, хотя варка собралась без проблем (mvn package), сервис в браузере недоступен (Request Url: http://localhost:8080/service/customer).

Answer (score 0):

Судя по структуре - это Maven Project, соответственно и подключать его нужно как Maven Project или сконвертировать в него: правый клик по проекту, Configure - Convert to Maven Project. После этих манипуляций появляется доступный для деплоя на сервере Tomcat ресурс, можно запускать и тестить.

Также для ясности, тут можно видеть два сервера: один из них отвечает за персист слой (Tomcat), второй - за обработку http запросов (Apache CXF). Но это ещё не точно )) Если кому есть, что добавить - просим!